# Blade em Laravel 5.4 - Como trabalhar com class="active" nos links do menu de uma página nesse cenário?

Tags: laravel

Eu tenho um menu com 3 possibilidades: pg1, pg2 ou pg3. A página é gerada em Blade, usando bootstrap.

```
<a href="#" class="active">pg1</a>
<a href="#">pg2</a>
<a href="#">pg3</a>
```

Eu teria que identifcar em qual rota estamos para ativar o menu correto.

Fazendo umas pesquisas na internet eu achei [essa resposta](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practice-for-handling-active-menu-item-in-l5) que poderia resolver o meu problema:  Dentro da view ...

```
<a href="#" {{{ (Request::is('pg1') ? 'class=active' : '')>pg1</a>
<a href="#" {{{ (Request::is('pg2') ? 'class=active' : '')>pg2</a>
<a href="#" {{{ (Request::is('pg3') ? 'class=active' : '')>pg3</a>
```

Ou seja, seria identificada a rota que solicitou a página e o a classe active seria carregada de acordo.

Porém essa resposta não me ajuda pois:

1. Estou na [versão 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests). Na resposta acima temos acesso ao método "is" diretamente através do uso da classe esttática Request. Na versão 5.4 eu teria que fazer uma injeção de dependência para usar o objeto Request e ai sim ter acesso ao metodo "is". Eu teria que fazer a injeção da dependência em todas as rotas? Ou existe alguma maneira sem injetar objetos nessa versão 5.4?
2. As minhas rotas possuem formatos um pouco diferente.

Assim:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{account}'], function (){
  Route::get('/pg1', function ($account) {
    return view('pg1');//pg1 do usuario
  });
  Route::get('/pg3', function ($account) {
    return view('pg3');//pg2 do usuario
  });
  Route::get('/pg3', function ($account) {
    return view('pg3');//pg3 do usuario
  });
});
```

Caso tenha 2 usuário paulo e beto.

Teríamos as seguintes rotas possíveis

```
paulo/pg1,
paulo/pg2,
paulo/pg3, 
beto/pg1,
beto/pg2,
beto/pg3,
```

Ou seja, sempre iria falhar no teste de verificação da rota para gerar o link ativo `<a href="#" {{{ (Request::is('pg1') ? 'class=active' : '')>pg1</a>`.

A única solução que vejo no momento seria fazer um teste de REGEX para verificar pg1 ou pg2 ou pg3.

Qual seria uma outra abordagem para evitar esse teste de REGEX?

Comment: já tentou usar `Request::route()->getName()` ? ao inves de `Request::is`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu costumo mandar isso como variável a partir do controller:

```
public function pg2() {
   ...
   return view()->with(['active' => 'pg2']);
}
```

Na view:

```
<a href="#" class="@if($active == 'pg1') active @endif">pg1</a>
<a href="#" class="@if($active == 'pg2') active @endif">pg2</a>
<a href="#" class="@if($active == 'pg3') active @endif">pg3</a>
```

Outra solução simples pode passar por dares nomes às rotas:

```
Route::get('/pag1', 'MeuController@pag1')->name('pag1');
Route::get('/pag2', 'MeuController@pag2')->name('pag2');
Route::get('/pag3', 'MeuController@pag3')->name('pag3');
```

Despois na view:

```
<a href="#" class="@if(Route::current()->getName() == 'pg1') active @endif">pg1</a>
<a href="#" class="@if(Route::current()->getName() == 'pg2') active @endif">pg2</a>
<a href="#" class="@if(Route::current()->getName() == 'pg3') active @endif">pg3</a>
```

Comment: Eu não testei, mas ia citar algo parecido, é este mesmo o caminho +1

Comment: Há inúmeras maneiras @GuilhermeNascimento, mas também acho que a primeira é a melhor (das que eu sei)

Comment: Deu certo. Acho que no meu caso só resolveria o primeiro exemplo pois estou trabalhando com master templates em blade. E o header carrega em um só lugar, independente da página que ele vai estar inserido

Comment: Funcionaria na mesma @zwitterion (quase a certeza), pois a rotas é só uma de cada vez. De qualquer maneira costumo optar pela primeira

Comment: Crreto @Miguel, eu estive pensando depois e percebi que vou ter que usar algo como o segundo exemplo. Eu estou fazendo testes e na verdade nao chamo a view de dentro das rotas. Normalmente chamo as view de dentro do controller. Entáo vou ter que encontrar uma maneira para passar essa variável para o controller e do controller para  as views. Echo que o caminho vai ser nomeando as rotas mesmo.

Comment: editei o meu post anterior